# How can I solve internal server errors in an app deployed on the meteor free servers?

Tags: mongodb, meteor, deployment

I just tried to deploy my app on a free meteor server. It seemed to work fine, but some tasks (methods I assume) are triggering an internal server error (500).

I wondered if it was related to the code minification so I tried to deploy it using `--debug` and it hasn't changed anything.

Since this is quite a large app, I am clueless on the cause since I can't get the error details. I can narrow it down to a few files, but I have no idea of where it comes from since it works just fine on my test server.

I don't know where to find the list of limitations of these free servers and I wonder if it comes from non allowed tasks.

For instance, I use several `Cursor.observe()` and I am not sure it is feasible with a free server. Moreover, I don't know if I must [create a dedicated user in mongo f](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/wiki/Oplog-Observe-Driver#oplogobservedriver-in-production)or the `Cursor.observe()` based publications.

I will try to deploy on a free EC2 instance to see if it makes any difference but I wish I could find a way to get some info on these errors.

---

EDIT: My bad, I just learnt that I can access to the logs using `meteor logs example.com`. It is indeed a `Cursor.observe()` related error. I'll try to understand the issue and come back to update the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well deploy to meteor.com has some limitations, my suggestion is to try a better approach of deployment, using an Amazon EC2 isntance, take a look to [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=11K_DSrhJzQ), where you will learn how to deploy your meteor app to Amazon EC2, Im sure that if your problem is related with server limitations you won't face problems with Amazon EC2, if your problem persists there too then your issue is not related to server limitations...

Comment: I solved the question using `meteor logs example.com`. Thank you for the video, I'll accept your answer :-)

Comment: The video was useful for us too!ç